# Use nodejs file system module at client side

Tags: node.js

Is it possible to use nodejs file system module at client side? I want to build a js file which interacts with file IO.

Thanks,
Meet

Answer (score 0):

Client side means plain javascript on website, this is what you mean right?

If yes then due to security reasons this is not feasible. Browsers has no access to IO of the device that is running as you already know ;)

Comment: Thanks Panagiotis Vrs. Does it apply to all built in nodejs modules?

Comment: Yes, the javascript you write in backend doesn't mean that has the same restrictions or access in the front end